# how to use gesture recognizer in 2 tableview of a single viewcontroller in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using Two `UITableview` in a single `viewcontroller`.

When i swipe(swipeleft) a cell in tableview2 that cell gets overlap on the tableview1.

assume the tableview is like

`tabelview1||tabelview2`        //in single viewcontroler

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: If i swipe(dismissing the cell from the tableview2) a cell in tableview2 it gets overlapped in tableview1.

Comment: i am unable to put the image. How to post the image its asking 10reputation like that.

Comment: how to post the image

Comment: Finally i got it ... it's the mistake of same cell identifier is used for both tableview. i changed the cell identifier . its gets working perfectly..